# How to include non Vcpkg on CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, lib, vcpkg

So I have a project which depends on opencv, which is installed with vcpkg. The project is build with cmake.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19.1)

project(mylib)

set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

link_libraries(${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp another_lib.cpp)
```

That works fine.

Now, instead of `vcpkg` provided opencv, I want to use opencv from

https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.4.0/opencv-4.4.0-vc14_vc15.exe/download

After installing it on `C:\opencv` I see there is `opencv\build\OpenCVConfig.cmake`, which `find_package` look for, right?

But how do I make cmake get this one instead of the one from vcpkg?

Comment: Offtopic: `CMakeList.txt` should not contain your computer specific paths, so this `set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake)` is a problem. In fact you should not alter `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` in you `CMakeList.txt`.

Comment: Which platform do you use? `~` in path suggest some POSIX system `c:\\` is Windows specific.

Comment: Got it about the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE `, and I'm targeting Win and macOS.

Comment: @AlanBirtles, after adding `set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH C:/opencv/build)`how can I confirm its not using opencv from vcpkg anymore?

Comment: Check `<PackageName>_VERSION`->`OpenCV_VERSION` value (I assume version of those two installations of OpenCV are different).

Comment: @AlanBirtles shouldn't I set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` instead?

Comment: @AlanBirtles  `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is for search modules, it won't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<PackageName>_DIR` variable pointing to where the config file is located. It works for any library which comes with a config file.
For you it would look like this:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/opencv/build")
```

Since it is incorrect to add hard-coded paths into persistent scripts, you can choose among different methods of providing this variable to your script:

- Console invocation: `cmake OpenCV_DIR="C:/opencv/build"`
- [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) (user)
- Local config by using some `LocalConfig.cmake` with the content above (`set(...)`), which you include in your main script like this: `include(LocalConfig.cmake)`